# how can i store List<object> in sharedpreferences using provider?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, provider

so basically this is my provider, what i want is how can i store the model data coming from provider to a shared preferences, and then how to decode it to show it in a bookmark page?

```
class bookmark extends ChangeNotifier{
  int _count = 0;
  List<bookmarkModel> bookM = [];
  
  void addCount(){
    _count++;
   notifyListeners();
  }
  
  void addItems(bookmarkModel i){
   bookM.add(i);
   notifyListeners();
  }

  int get  count => _count;
  List<bookmarkModel> get  bookMList => bookM;

}
```

here is my model:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class bookmarkModel{
  String title;
  String subtitle;
  int num;

  bookmarkModel({this.title, this.subtitle, this.num});

  bookmarkModel.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json) :
  title = json['title'], 
  subtitle = json['sutitle'], 
  num = json['num'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson()=>{
    'title':title,
    'subtitle':subtitle,
    'num': num
  }; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SharedPreferences` should only be used to store small and simple values. It's not meant to be used as a Database.

You can use `sharedPreferences` to store `bool`, `String`, `int` and simple `List`s (not lists of objects or maps). As far as I know, it even cannot store `doubles`.

Try using a [SQflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) or [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) (No-SQL) to store more complex or extensive data locally.

Comment: I get it, you are right, I don't know nothing about hive and sqflite takes me a little bit too much time, thought there is someway to do so, anyways thanks for you honest knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You already have `toJosn` and `fromJson` ready to use, you just need to convert `bookM` to a map `josnEnode()` and the get it back using `josnDecode()`.

try the code below:

```
void saveBookmark() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final String List = jsonEncode(bookM, toEncodable: (c)=> c.toJson());        
    await prefs.setString('BookMarkList', List);
  }
```

```
  void loadBookMark() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final String saved = prefs.getString('BookMarkList');
    final List<dynamic> decoded = jsonDecode(saved);
    bookM = decoded.map((bookmark) => bookmarkModel.fromJson(bookmark));
  }
```

Comment: mmmm sorry for saying this but my brain stopped working and i dont know where exactly to use these methods, i used both of them in the provider class and toJson has an error line under, do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you share what the error says? And also since those methods are in a provider you can call them anywhere you want, saving could be done using a button and loading by calling loadBookMark in your initState or something like this but it doesn't have to be initiated inside of the provider itself